# Is it safe to run tune2fs -l /dev/device on a mounted filesystem?

Tags: filesystem, ext4

Is it safe to run tune2fs -l /dev/device on a mounted filesystem? That is, listing the current values (I'm trying to do this to see if the filesystem is marked as clean).

If it's ok, is there a definitive source where this is documented so that I can rest assured I won't corrupt something?

Thanks

Comment: Not a guarantee, but I've used `tune2fs -l` on mounted systems, and also changed the Errors behavior and Maximum mount count, without causing any apparent errors in the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

`tune2fs -l /dev/device` does read the superblock, so does not change anything on the file system. It probably is safe to use on a mounted volume. However, I found that I can accomplish the same thing with `dumpe2fs -h`, for which man pages explicitly document that it can work on mounted filesystems.

Comment: Citation: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/dumpe2fs.8.html `Note: When used with a mounted filesystem, the printed information may be old or inconsistent.` (I guess the "when" at least implies it's expected people will do it.)

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommend to run `tune2fs` on a mounted file system. It is documented in the manpages while executing `tune2fs` with `-E` option:

[`man tune2fs`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/tune2fs.8.html):

```
Use only if absolutely certain the
device is not currently mounted or being
fscked, or major filesystem corruption can result.
```